# opening a word file in browser using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download

I am trying to open/download a word file on a browser using C#. The process is working for PDF files, but not for .doc files. It donwloads as a "application/octet-stream (100 kB)"

My code is:

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(@"~\Content\documetfile.doc"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        return File(fs, "documentfile.doc");
```

What do i need to do to make it download as a word file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify correct content type: "application/vnd.ms-word":

```
  return File(fs, "application/vnd.ms-word", "documentfile.doc");
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this open the file at a particular Bookmark within the document?

Comment: @AntDC I don't think so, but you can always ask new question.